# Provide a UIWebview with a querystring when using loadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, base-url, querystringparameter

I am loading an HTML file into an UIWebview from the MainBundle and would like to pass in a query string, since the HTML file checks for a GET parameter (?device=1) to do some extra calculations. I also need to provide the UIWebview with a baseURL (to intercept the requests made from the HTML file).

Currently, I use the following:

```
[myWebView loadData:dataFromHTMLFile MIMEType:mimeType 
   textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mycustomprotocol:///%@",htmlFileName]]];
```

I know I can use the code below to load a file into an UIWebview with some GET parameters, but that doesn't allow me to specify a base URL:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlWithGETParameter cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)10.0 ];
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Is there a way I can load the data into the UIWebview with a base URL and a query string?

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible but this will be done by your server end developer .If you want to open a Webpage with respect to the query parameter that you send in request then that will be handled at server end.Your server end developer need to response the webpage with respect to the query parameter value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The thing is though that the "webpage" I am trying to load is a file embedded in my app. This file is a library that I am not allowed to change. I am looking at a way to send ?device=1 to the watch.html file (watch.html?device=1), but I am using loadData which doesn't let me send a query parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but this will be done by your server end developer .If you want to open a Webpage with respect to the query parameter that you send in request then that will be handled at server end.Your server end developer need to response the webpage with respect to the query parameter value.